# limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query which returns all rows until the sum of one of the columns value reaches a certain value.

For example in the table below:

```
           DATE             ETC      Meeting
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    85482        1
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    47228        2
    2013-02-02 00:00:00    12026        4
    2013-02-03 00:00:00    78927        6
    2013-02-04 00:00:00    85662        2
    2013-03-05 00:00:00    47978        1
    2013-08-07 00:00:00     8582        1
```

If I want to get the rows until the sum of column `Meeting` equals 7.

```
           DATE             ETC      Meeting
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    85482        1
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    47228        2
    2013-02-02 00:00:00    12026        4
```

If I want to get the rows until the sum of column `Meeting` equals 13.

```
     DATE                   ETC      Meeting
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    85482        1
    2013-02-01 00:00:00    47228        2
    2013-02-02 00:00:00    12026        4
    2013-02-03 00:00:00    78927        6
```

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL...? What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution.

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY/no way of establishing the sequence in which rows are to be considered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way which should work in MySQL :

```
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Type,
  O.MyAmountCol,
  (SELECT
     sum(MyAmountCol) FROM Table1
   WHERE Id <= O.Id) 'RunningTotal'
FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <= 7
```

It involves calculating a running total and selecting records while the running total is less than or equal to the given number, in this case `7`.

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a038/2)

Comment: Where did id come from?

Comment: Note this is likely O(N^2) query on the db server as the sub-select grows towards the end of the query, and there is no early stopping either, all sums will be evaluated. Provided the scope of the selects is small, it has the advantage of being a single query (so no need for stored procedure etc).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way to do it without a stored procedure:

```
SET @msum := 0;
SELECT t1.* 
FROM (
    SELECT m.*,  
          (@msum := @msum + m.meetings) AS cumulative_meetings
    FROM meetings m 
    ORDER BY m.date ASC
) t1 
WHERE t1.cumulative_meetings <= 7;
```

Comment: this is actually a better, faster solution for large amounts of data. thank you.

Comment: If the every row has more meetings than X, this query will return 0 row.

Answer (score 6):

This one outperforms all.

```
SET @runningTotal=0;
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Type,
  O.MyAmountCol,
  @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol as 'RunningTotal',
  @runningTotal := @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol
FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <=7;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53fcc/4)

Take a look at execution plans for both queries.

Comment: Thanks for this. For those who want to use `WHERE` query with this, use `AND` in `HAVING` instead

Answer (score 1):

Hemant you do not state the RDBMS that use. Here is a script in t-sql that you can use in order to solve your problem.

```
DECLARE @numberToReach INT;
SET @numberToReach = 10; --you can change this

DECLARE @date DATETIME;
DECLARE @etc VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @meeting INT;
DECLARE @temp_sum INT;

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
    (
        Dates DATETIME,
        Etcs VARCHAR(20),
        Meeting INT,
    )

DECLARE tempcursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT *
        FROM YourTABLENAME
OPEN tempcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor INTO @date, @etc, @meeting;

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @temp_sum = @temp_sum + @meeting;
    IF @temp_sum < @numberToReach 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempTable
        (
            Dates,
            Etcs,
            Meeting
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @date, 
            @etc, 
            @meeting
        )

        FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor INTO @date, @etc, @meeting;
    END 
END

SELECT * FROM #tempTable

CLOSE tempcursor
DEALLOCATE tempcursor

DROP TABLE  #tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

As no DBMS is given, the following is an ANSI SQL solution which works on a wide range of DBMS:

```
select *
from (
    select date_column, 
           etc, 
           sum(Meeting) over (order by date_column asc) run_sum
    from meetings
) t
where run_sum <= 7
order by date_column asc;
```

(I used the column name `date_column` instead of `date` because `DATE` is a reserved word in SQL and should not be used as a column name to avoid problems)

Comment: Date is not a reserved word, and dates are not unique in the example provided

Comment: @Strawberry: yes `date` **is** a keyword (but not a reserved one). Even MySQL thinks so: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html and the dates don't have to be unique for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly way:

```
SELECT *
FROM meetings m1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(m2.Meeting) 
       FROM meetings m2 
       WHERE m2.DATE < m1.DATE OR (m2.DATE = m1.DATE AND m2.ETC >= m1.ETC)) <= 7
```

The ordering is based on `DATE` first, then `ETC` in descending order, since that seems to be what we have to go on. Note that if that is not unique, *you will get the wrong result*.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, I think you can use the SUM analytic function. You can refer here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/sum.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SQL Server, then use [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx).