# MySQL: Select LAST N rows while SUM less Then number

Tags: php, mysql, sum, having

I've got a huge table:

```
+------+---------+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
|ticker|data_date|price|count|oper_id|ext_nr|oper_summ|
+------+---------+-----+-----+-------+------+---------+
|SBER  |2015-08..|70.00|15   |0      |251528|1050.00  |
|AFLT  |2015-08..|30.00|5    |0      |251525|150.00   |
|SBER  |2015-08..|69.00|10   |1      |251521|690.00   |
|SBER  |2015-08..|71.00|15   |1      |251513|1065.00  |
|SBER  |2015-08..|72.00|15   |0      |251512|1080.00  |

  data_date format: 2015-01-05 09:59:59
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_ticker_ext_nr` (`ticker`,`ext_nr`)
```

I need to SELECT LAST N rows WHERE SUM(oper_summ) will be LESS THEN 10000

I've found similar topic: [limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql)

```
SELECT
  O.ext_nr,
  O.price,   O.count,
  O.oper_summ,
  (SELECT
     sum(oper_summ) FROM Table1
   WHERE ext_nr <= O.ext_nr) 'RunningTotal'
FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <= 10000
```

but unable to make it work in my coditions...

Found a solution:

```
SET @msum := 0;
select t1.* from 
(select m.*, 
(@msum := @msum + m.oper_summ) as cumul_oper_summ from jos_fintools_data m order by m.data_date DESC ) 
t1 where t1.cumul_oper_summ <= 10000;
```

credits goes to toomanyredirects: [limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql?lq=1)

Comment: Show us what you have so far, at least that will gove us a clue

Comment: ok: i need to find last rows total sum of which would be less then 2150; in my example it will be prices: 71 and 72 sum(oper_summ) = 2145 < 2150

Comment: We are here to help you not to provide some code. Show us what you have tried and we'll try to help you. And edit your question instead of writing important informations ins comment

Comment: SELECT
  O.ext_nr,
  O.price,   O.count,
  O.oper_summ,
  (SELECT
     sum(oper_summ) FROM Table1
   WHERE ext_nr <= O.ext_nr) 'RunningTotal'
FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <= 10000

Comment: Michael: Edit your question with any extra detail. Its unreadable as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @msum := 0;
select t1.* from 
(select m.*, 
(@msum := @msum + m.oper_summ) as cumul_oper_summ from jos_fintools_data m order by m.data_date DESC ) 
t1 where t1.cumul_oper_summ <= 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT O.ext_nr, O.price, O.count, O.oper_summ,
             (@os := @os + oper_summ) as RunningTotal
      FROM Table1 O CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @os := 0) params
      ORDER BY data_date desc
     ) o
HAVING RunningTotal <= 10000;
```

Note:  you need to order by something in the subquery.  I'm not sure what the right column is.  My best guess is the date column.

Comment: No... i need to SUMM the Whole column, but then i add ordering result of sums equals to oper_summ: 
+------------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------------+
| ext_nr     | price     | count | oper_summ | RunningTotal       |
+------------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------------+
| 2515424031 |  40.40500 |     5 | 202.02500 |            202.025 | And what '@os' meen?..