# Stop sum when value reached

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Assume Table1:

```
|PaymentID|CashAmount|
----------------------
|   P1    |      3000|
|   P2    |      5000|
|   P3    |      8000|
|   P4    |       700|
|   P5    |      5500|
|   P6    |      1900|
```

If I want to sum of CashAmount to be 'at least' 9000. PaymentID order should be the same.
Expected Result:

```
|PaymentID|CashAmount|
----------------------
|   P1    |      3000|
|   P2    |      5000|
|   P3    |      8000|
```

If I want to sum of CashAmount to be 'at least' 4000. PaymentID order should be the same.
Expected Result:

```
|PaymentID|CashAmount|
----------------------
|   P1    |      3000|
|   P2    |      5000|
```

I had a look at [limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql). But the accepted answer is not working with MSSQL and is not exactly what I'm looking for. Most of the answers there I've tested and they return only rows that the total amount is less than, not at least specific value.

Comment: Which SQL Server version? This is quite easy with a running sum using a window function.

Comment: Does your table have a sort column? At least the first two DATE values are the same, the rest is "running". Is this a typo or could there be several entries with the same date? In this case you MUST provide any secure sorting criteria otherwise your output gets random...

Comment: @Shnugo, I have updated the example. Yes, the table should be sorted according to PaymentID. I want to get the CashAmount until it had reached the specified amount. The link I gave in original post returns result before it reaches the amount. For example, if I input CashAmount of 4000, it will return just P1 which is 3000 < 4000. What I want is P1 and P2 which is 8000 > 4000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your new input I changed my approach slightly. Hope this is what you need...

EDIT: Here's the version with SUM(x) OVER(...):

```
DECLARE @payment TABLE(PaymentID VARCHAR(10),CashAmount INT);
INSERT INTO @payment VALUES
 ('P1',3000)
,('P2',5000)
,('P3',8000)
,('P4',700)
,('P5',5500)
,('P6',1900);

DECLARE @myMinToReach INT=9000;

WITH SortedPayment AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PaymentID) AS inx  
          ,SUM(CashAmount) OVER(ORDER BY PaymentID) AS Summa
    FROM @payment
)
SELECT * FROM SortedPayment
WHERE inx<=(SELECT TOP 1 x.inx 
           FROM SortedPayment AS x
           WHERE Summa>@myMinToReach
           ORDER BY Summa ASC);
```

And that's the old version for SQL-Server < 2012

```
DECLARE @payment TABLE(PaymentID VARCHAR(10),CashAmount INT);
INSERT INTO @payment VALUES
 ('P1',3000)
,('P2',5000)
,('P3',8000)
,('P4',700)
,('P5',5500)
,('P6',1900);

DECLARE @myMinToReach INT=4000;

WITH SortedPayment AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PaymentID) AS inx,*
    FROM @payment
)
,Accumulated AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SortedPayment.*
              ,Accumulated.Summa
        FROM SortedPayment
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT SUM(ps2.CashAmount) AS Summa 
            FROM SortedPayment AS ps2 
            WHERE ps2.inx<=SortedPayment.inx 
        ) AS Accumulated
    ) AS tbl
)

SELECT * FROM Accumulated
WHERE inx<=(SELECT TOP 1 x.inx 
           FROM Accumulated AS x
           WHERE Summa>@myMinToReach
           ORDER BY Summa ASC);
```

Comment: I have tried this with my updated example. if @myMaxToReach = 4000, then it will return only P1 which is 3000. I want P1 and P2 which exceeds 4000.

Comment: @Boy, which version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Boy, Ahh, this moment I saved my edited code. Should work, but with SQL 2014 there'd be a simpler approach with SUM-OVER... Please vote up and/or mark as helpful, thx

Comment: @Boy, added code for higher SQL-Server version. The SUM-OVER does the accumulation more elegant...

Answer (score 3):

### SQL Server 2005 and Later

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName t 
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Amount)
                    FROM TableName 
                    WHERE [Date]  <= t.[DATE]) c(AmtSum)
WHERE AmtSum <= 13
```

### SQL Server 2012 and Later

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
        SELECT *
             ,SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY [Date], Amount) AmtSum
        FROM TableName 
      )t
WHERE AmtSum <= 13
```

Comment: try this with the data I provide in my answer... The version for 2005 and later cannot handle the two identical dates... Probably a typo... The second version doesn't work here, but - to be honest - I don't see the mistake ("wrong syntax near 'order'")

Comment: ups... my bad. Was connected to an instance of SQL2008 without being aware of that... This SUM-OVER is the most elegant and easy...

Comment: This answer is similar to the original link I provided. However this is not what I was looking for. If I change AmtSum <= 13 to AmtSum <= 12, it will return only first 3 rows which is 1+2+4 = 7. I want 'at least' 12 so it should return first 4 rows (1+2+4+6 = 13).

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @s int;

update table set rc=row_count() over (order by date)


declare @i int;
set @i=1;

while @s<=12 or @i<100000
   set @s=@s+(select amount from table where rc=@i+1);
   set @i=@i+1;
end

// @s has at least 12
```

Comment: If there are not enough amounts, goes in infinte loop.

Comment: SQL is a set based language... Procedural approaches are possible but should be avoided. There are very rare cases where you really need a loop or a cursor - so avoid them...