# How to limit rows to where SUM of a column equals to certain value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Based on the link I refer, I have tried to do the same but got an error

[limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql)

Firstly, here is the **studyplan table**:

[image]

If I want to get the rows until the SUM of CREDIT column equal to 18 :

[image]

If I want to get the rows until the SUM of CREDIT column equals to 20 :

[image]

This is the SQL statement I try:

```
SELECT t.matricsno,t.sem,t.credit,
(SELECT SUM(credit) FROM studyplan
WHERE matricsno = 'D031310087')
FROM studyplan t
HAVING SUM(credit) = 18
ORDER BY t.sem,t.subjectcode;
```

And the error I have got is : **ORA-00937: not a single-group group function**

Thank you for your response and help.

Comment: You can only use aggregate functions, such as `SUM`, when doing a `GROUP BY` (MySQL does not require this). Doesn't http://stackoverflow.com/a/14893074/112968 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/14890990/112968 do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for using a cumulative sum.

Assuming the order of the rows is unambiguously defined by the columns `sem` and `subjectcode`, as your query implies, you can write the query like this:

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               sum(t.credit) over (order by t.sem, t.subjectcode) as credit_sum
          from studyplan t
         where t.matricsno = 'D031310087')
 where credit_sum <= 20 -- adjust to desired number of credits
 order by sem, subjectcode
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'm a little confused between MySQL and Oracle. But well.. I'm still newbie though.

Comment: Thank you again sir, I'm about to ask too. :D

Comment: May I ask a little more regarding the question? Is it possible to move to next row in the same column?

Which mean if the first run it will get the sum of Credit from row 1 to 7, then the next run it will get the sum of Credit from 8 to 15.

Comment: Sorry. I don't quite understand what you mean.  Consider asking a new question, and include sample data and expected results like you did in this question.  It will help understand you better, and will also be helpful to you, because others will have a chance to respond as well.