# How to limit rows to where SUM of a column equals to certain value and go to next row Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Based on my question here, I have managed to get the answer.. but then a new problem arise that I need to display it like this :

Firstly, here is the **studyplan table**

[image]

So now, on the first run, it will display like this if I want to get the rows until SUM of Credit column equal to 18 :

[image]

But, then on the second run, I want it to be displayed like this if I want to get the rows until the SUM of Credit column equal to 21 :

[image]

How I want it to SUM the column at the next row? Do I have to make 2 SQL statement?

Here is the success code from the first run :

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.*,
SUM(t.credit) OVER (PARTITION BY t.matricsno ORDER BY t.sem, t.subjectcode)
AS credit_sum
FROM studyplan t)
WHERE credit_sum <= 17 AND matricsno = 'D031310087';
```

Thank you for your response and time.

Here is the link, [How to limit rows to where SUM of a column equals to certain value in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471704/how-to-limit-rows-to-where-sum-of-a-column-equals-to-certain-value-in-oracle)

Comment: No, you don't. Check `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions for Oracle. If you need to store this information in order to be able to access it from separate SQL queries, you need to store the information about last pulled `id` and then use it in `WHERE` clause to look forward and `UPDATE` that last_pulled_id again after selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of an odd requirement.  But, yes, if you want 2 different result sets, you'll need separate 2 SQL statements.  But for each additional statement, you would only need to tweak your condition on `credit_sum`.

For instance, if for your 1st query you want to get the rows up to when the credit sum reaches 18, you would do:

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               sum(t.credit) over (order by t.sem, t.subjectcode) as credit_sum
          from studyplan t
         where t.matricsno = 'D031310087')
 where credit_sum <= 18
 order by sem, subjectcode
```

For your 2nd query, you say you want the rows where the credit sum reaches 21, but ignoring the rows returned by the 1st query.  Another way to express that requirement is to return the rows for which the cumulative credit sum is between 19 and 39 (inclusive). So then, it simply becomes a matter of modifying the filter on `credit_sum` to use a `between` condition:

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               sum(t.credit) over (order by t.sem, t.subjectcode) as credit_sum
          from studyplan t
         where t.matricsno = 'D031310087')
 where credit_sum between 19 and 39
 order by sem, subjectcode
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I don't know it can get the next row in that way.  But it should be between 19 and 40 right? Because the next row should be 21 credit sum.

Comment: Test it to be sure, but 19 to 39 inclusive covers 21 numbers by my count.  In any case, you can use the general principle and tweak it to your exact needs.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. I forgot that 19 is counted as well. sorry sir haha