# Retrieve Postgresql rows limiting to SUM(column) <2000

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get all the ids of a customers invoices, but limiting the total monetary value of invoices to 2000. The basic idea is to figure out how many invoices a payment of 2000 dollars would apply to. 
What I have tried :

```
SELECT id 
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING SUM(total) <= 2000.00 AND customer_id = 4
```

But this gives me a `column "invoices.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error.

I could also use several transactions in Python to figure out how many invoices a 2000 dollar payment would cover, but I would like to stay to a single transaction if possible. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some potentially relevant reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql Includes an agnostic ANSI-SQL solution that should work in postgres.

Comment: You are the best! I never found that post, probably because I did not know what to search for.

Comment: Glad that helped; I think I'll throw a dupe vote on this one so it can live on as a search target.