# Get the rows where column/field sum equals a certain value

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I want to write the code for a Linq Clause in VB.NET or C# which returns all records until the sum of one of the columns value reaches a certain value and grouped by an other column..

For now I have that in a MySQL Clause:

```
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Supp,
  O.TotalCol,
  (SELECT
     sum(TotalCol) FROM Table1
   WHERE Id <= O.Id) 'bTotal'
FROM Table1 O
HAVING bTotal <= 50000
```

Code I already done:

The Object Class:

```
Class Invoices
        Public id As Integer
        Public supplier As String
        Public total As Decimal
        Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal supplier As String, ByVal total As Decimal)
            Me.id = id
            Me.supplier = supplier
            Me.total = total 
        End Sub
End Class
```

The Ungrouped List:

```
Dim LInvoicesPrincipal As New List(Of Invoices)()

Dim InvoiceItem As Invoices

InvoiceItem = New Invoices(1, "SUPP 1", 45000)
LInvoicesPrincipal.Add(InvoiceItem)
InvoiceItem = New Invoices(2, "SUPP 1", 6000)
LInvoicesPrincipal.Add(InvoiceItem)
InvoiceItem = New Invoices(3, "SUPP 2", 15000)
LInvoicesPrincipal.Add(InvoiceItem)
InvoiceItem = New Invoices(4, "SUPP 2", 6000)
LInvoicesPrincipal.Add(InvoiceItem)
InvoiceItem = New Invoices(5, "SUPP 1", 4000)
LInvoicesPrincipal.Add(InvoiceItem)
```

The grouping in LINQ, by provider (I need the rule that limits the sum of the totals to a certain value (50000 to be precise)):

```
Dim LGroups

LGroups = _
    From oInvoices In LInvoicesPrincipal _
    Group oInvoices By oInvoices.supplier _
    Into Group Select Group
```

And a For Each that allows me to validate the grouping:

```
For Each EachList As Invoices() In LGroups

    For Each EachItem As Invoices In EachList

    Next

Next
```

All this currently returns me lists like these:

```
Group 1:
Invoices(1, "SUPP 1", 45000)
Invoices(2, "SUPP 1", 6000)
Invoices(5, "SUPP 1", 4000)

Group 2:
Invoices(3, "SUPP 2", 15000)
Invoices(4, "SUPP 2", 6000)
```

BUT... What I want to get is something like this:

```
Group 1:
Invoices(1, "SUPP 1", 45000)
Invoices(5, "SUPP 1", 4000)

Group 2:
Invoices(2, "SUPP 1", 6000)

Group 3:
Invoices(3, "SUPP 2", 15000)
Invoices(4, "SUPP 2", 6000)
```

(The sum of the values must be <= 50000 per group)

Comment: Please provide some arrangement and code which you already done.

Comment: Going by your last (deleted) question, its more of a combination thing or a Best Fit algorithm.  I am not sure you can do either in SQL

Comment: Maybe it's a combination of both... I'm already cycled with the same idea in my head, I need a breather...

Comment: I think is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql?rq=1 but in vb.net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Bin Packing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) which works to limit the number of bins required to pack a given set of items.  You seem most concerned with limiting the aggregate total to <= 50000 by supplier versus how many Invoice Groups are created. The **by supplier** element seems to be mentioned only in passing.

- This should do what you want, but it is not really a Best-Fit approach.
- I used more data to get a better picture: 5 suppliers and 30 Invoices
- Suppliers and Invoices were created randomly, so each Supplier did not have 6 invoices
- 1 Supplier-Invoice set was not random so I could test particular datasets

You already have an `Invoice` class but mine is slightly different:

```vb
Public Class Invoice
    Public Property Id As Int32
    Public Property Supplier As String
    Public Property Total As Decimal

    Public Property GroupId As Int32
    ...
```

I strongly advise you to use actual `Properties` instead of public fields.  This allows you to display the results in a `DataGridView` for debugging.  The new `GroupId` property allows the code to identify which invoice items have already been added to an `InvoiceGroup`:

```vb
Public Class InvoiceGrp
    Public Property GroupId As Int32
    Public Property Supplier As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Total As Decimal
        Get  
            Return Invoices.Sum(Function(k) k.Total)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Invoices As New List(Of Invoice)
    ...
```

There is also a `ToString()` override and a `Count` property for debugging.  First, the 'raw' Invoice list needs to be grouped by Supplier before each of them can be processed:

```vb
' group the invoices by supplier
Dim grpData = Invoices.GroupBy(Function(g) g.Supplier).ToArray()

' collection to store the results
Dim groupedInvoices = New List(Of InvoiceGrp)

Dim groupId = 1
' create invoice groups one supplier group at a time
For Each item In grpData
    Dim gi = GroupInvoices(item, 50000, groupId)   ' add ToArray() for debug
    groupedInvoices.AddRange(gi)

    ' the GroupId gets incremented for each supplier
    '  group, use the last one for the start value in the next
    '  supplier group 
    groupId = gi.Max(Of Int32)(Function(k) k.GroupId)
Next
```

The invoice totals were selected at random from:
 `{4000, 2500, 5000, 10000, 15000, 45000, 6000, 25000}`.

. `GroupInvoice` method and a helper:

```vb
Private Iterator Function GroupInvoices(grp As IEnumerable(Of Invoice),
                                        Limit As Decimal,
                                        grpId As Int32) As IEnumerable(Of InvoiceGrp)

    ' make a copy so we can remove those grouped
    Dim myGrp = New List(Of Invoice)(grp.
                                      Where(Function(k) k.GroupId = -1).
                                      OrderByDescending(Function(k) k.Total).
                                      ToArray())

    While (myGrp.Count > 0)
        grpId += 1
        ' NewInvoiceGroup does the actual Group creation
        Dim newGrp = NextInvoiceGroup(myGrp, Limit, grpId)
        ' remove grouped items from the ToDo list
        myGrp.RemoveAll(Function(r) newGrp.Invoices.Contains(r))

        Yield newGrp
    End While
End Function

Private Function NextInvoiceGroup(items As List(Of Invoice),
                                 Limit As Decimal,
                                 nextGrp As Int32) As InvoiceGrp

    ' this creates one InvGrp with as many Invoices
    ' as will fit.  
    Dim InvG = New InvoiceGrp With {.Supplier = items(0).Supplier, .GroupId = nextGrp}

    For Each inv In items
        If InvG.Total + inv.Total <= Limit Then
            ' tag Invoice with the InvoiceGrp Id
            inv.GroupId = nextGrp
            InvG.Invoices.Add(inv)
        End If
    Next

    Return InvG
End Function
```

**Important Notes**

- Each group from the linq result with `N` number of invoices is passed to `GroupInvoices`.
- It puts them in order by amount (total), then calls `NextInvoiceGroup` to actually create group totaling no more then 50k.
- It is an `Iterator` which allows it to return each group as it is created.
- The invoices in each group created are removed from the list so it knows it is done when there are no more.  Likewise, each Invoice has a `GroupId` so the code knows which ones have already been added to a group.
- `NextInvoiceGroup` iterates all the invoices adding each to a new `InvoiceGrp` until it reaches 50k or runs out of items.
- There is no Best Fit/Bin Packing logic involved (and was not mentioned in the post), so the first groups for a Supplier will tend to be "fuller" (closer to 50k) and the last will be any leftovers.
- The `GroupId` should be a unique value for all groups
- At the end, you not only have InvoiceGrps, but each invoice also has an indicator which group it belongs to.
- If an `Iterator` method confuses you, it could be refactored to create and return a `List(Of InvoiceGroup)`
- If you print the contents to the console window, you can sometimes see that if you swapped some items from one group to another, the leftover could fit in some other Group. This is naturally going to be dependent on the data:

Debug dump:

```vb
For Each grp In groupedInvoices
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Grp# {1}: ct: {2} tot: {3}", grp.Supplier, grp.GroupId,
                      grp.Invoices.Count, grp.Total)
    For Each inv In grp.Invoices
        Console.WriteLine("Supp: {0} Inv#: {1} Tot: {2}",
                          inv.Supplier, inv.Id, inv.Total)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Results (excluding the Non Random supplier group)

> Alpha Grp# 1: ct: 4 tot: 50000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 2 Tot: 25000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 14 Tot: 15000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 8 Tot: 5000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 16 Tot: 5000
>
> Alpha Grp# 2: ct: 3 tot: 13000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 22 Tot: 5000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 1 Tot: 4000
>   Supp: Alpha Inv#: 6 Tot: 4000
>
> Delta Grp# 3: ct: 2 tot: 50000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 4 Tot: 45000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 3 Tot: 5000
>
> Delta Grp# 4: ct: 5 tot: 22500
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 5 Tot: 6000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 21 Tot: 6000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 11 Tot: 4000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 12 Tot: 4000
>   Supp: Delta Inv#: 9 Tot: 2500
>
> Echo Grp# 5: ct: 2 tot: 50000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 23 Tot: 45000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 24 Tot: 5000
>
> Echo Grp# 6: ct: 2 tot: 50000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 7 Tot: 25000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 18 Tot: 25000
>
> Echo Grp# 7: ct: 3 tot: 50000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 20 Tot: 25000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 19 Tot: 15000
>   Supp: Echo Inv#: 25 Tot: 10000
>
> FoxTrot Grp# 8: ct: 2 tot: 50000
>   Supp: FoxTrot Inv#: 15 Tot: 45000
>   Supp: FoxTrot Inv#: 13 Tot: 5000
>
> FoxTrot Grp# 9: ct: 1 tot: 45000
>   Supp: FoxTrot Inv#: 17 Tot: 45000
>
> FoxTrot Grp# 10: ct: 1 tot: 6000
>   Supp: FoxTrot Inv#: 10 Tot: 6000

Comment: Excellent explanation and resolution! Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.