# Django query - get first x elements which together exceed a specific amount for a field

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I want to request the first x elements which together exceeds a specific amount and I don’t know if this is somehow possible.
So assuming that this is my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
     price = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

Now if I order the `Articles` by the `price` I want the first `Articles` which together exceed the `price` of let’s say 100 Dollars.
Is this somehow possible with annotating, summing, extra() or whatever??

```
Article.objects.order_by("price")
```

for example:
I have 3 Articles:

```
Article1 (price=50 Dollar)
Article2 (price=60 Dollar)
Article3 (price=20 Dollar)
```

....Now I want the Articles which together exceed the price of 100 Dollar...so this would be Article1 AND Article2. Together the value is 110 Dollars

This answer in raw sql statements would dir he trick but I don’t know how to resolve that with django syntax
[limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql)

Comment: How do you say first x elements ? Created first ?

Comment: Let‘s say I have 3 Articles: Article1 (price=50 Dollar) Article2 (price=60 Dollar) and Article3 (price=20 Dollar)....Now I want the Articles which together exceed the price of 100 Dollar...so this would be Article1 AND Article2. Together the value is 110 Dollars

Comment: I cannot think of anything without using a forloop.

Comment: I found an answer here in raw sql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql But how is this working with Django syntax? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to this purely with a database query. The SQL question you linked to has answers that require a stored procedure, or that are very expensive (O(N^2)).

You can achieve the same thing with an iterator query that is efficient to run, and requires very simple manipulation in Python. Something like this:

```
articles = Article.objects.order_by("price").iterator()
to_update = []
total = 0
for article in articles:
    total += article.price
    if total > 100:
        break
    to_update.append(article.pk)

# Select the affected objects for update
Article.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk__in=to_update)
```

Because you're using `iterator()` you will only be fetching the items you need from the database.

Comment: What is with this: Article.objects.annotate(total_price=Sum(‚price‘)).filter(total_price__lte=100) ? I think I will give this a try

Comment: Try it... I am not sure it will work and if it does it will be O(N^2), more expensive than just iterating.

Comment: the problem is that i need to do a select_for_update and this is just possible on query sets :/

Comment: You can still achieve that, sort of - I've edited my answer to show how. Your only other option IMO is to use raw SQL.

Comment: Ok that‘s a possibility but what if during iterating another thread changes the prices of the articles? This be a problem

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar: Every solution mus use at least a subquery, even a complicated with `GROUP BY ... HAVING Sum(...) > ...`. Then a race condition is possible also with  [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). A stronger lock LOCK IN SHARE MODE would be necessary. I'm afraid that your requirements together are too much. On the other hand, you can easily check that the sum of rows from the second locked query is enough and minimal. I vote up, as it is the best possible universal and realistic solution by Django.