# How do I select this using Mysqli in php

Tags: mysql

How do I select users from the database where the sum of their salaries will be equal to some amount..

```
"select * from users where sum(salary)=10000";
```

The sum of 4 users salary can bring the total 10000.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql this link solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

SELECT O.*, (SELECT sum(salary) FROM users WHERE Id = O.Id) 'RunningTotal' FROM users O WHERE RunningTotal = 10000

Comment: Using HAVING without GROUP BY is wierd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql

Similar question is present in this link

Comment: thanks,, but this is not suming the salary.. it grings everything again.... i want it to return the users with the amount they contributed to 10000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql     has solve the problem