# How to fetch MySQL rows until the sum of a certain column exceeds the threshold?

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

I've been searching through StackOverflow and the closest one that I've found is [to use custom variable inside subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891362/4286919). But the suggested solution has two shortcomings.

#### Table

`+----+-------+-------------+
| id | type  | MyAmountCol |
+----+-------+-------------+
| 1  | 85482 | 10          |
+----+-------+-------------+
| 2  | 47228 | 20          |
+----+-------+-------------+
| 3  | 12026 | 40          |
+----+-------+-------------+`

1. When every row has cannot meet the condition, (i.e. if every value is larger than the threshold value.) no row is returned.

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f48b/1)

Query

```
SET @runningTotal=0;
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Type,
  O.MyAmountCol,
  @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol as 'RunningTotal',
  @runningTotal := @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol

FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <=5;
```

Returned

```
0 Row(s)
```

2. When the condition is caught in the middle, (i.e. if the first two values are 10 and 20, and the threshold is 15) the sum of returned values are always less than or equal to the threshold.

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f48b/2)

Query

```
SET @runningTotal=0;
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Type,
  O.MyAmountCol,
  @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol as 'RunningTotal',
  @runningTotal := @runningTotal + O.MyAmountCol

FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <=15;
```

Returned

```
1   85482   10  10 (1 Row)
```

The desired result is this. In the first example fiddle, I want the first row (id=`1`, type=`85842`) returned. In the second example fiddle, I want rows with id=`1` , type=`85842` and id=`2`, type=`47228` returned.

Putting it differently, what I'm trying to do is slightly different from what I've found and it doesn't seem to achieve it with that approach. I want the fewest number of sequential rows that exceed the target value. Is there any way for this with only MySQL (query), or should I solve this in the application level?

Comment: Can you please show your expected output in tabular or any way (to understand).

Comment: @S_sauden Thanks for your comment. From the first example fiddle, I want the row with type `85842` (id=1) returned. From the second example fiddle, I want the rows with type `85482`(id=1) and `47228`(id=2) returned.

Comment: @GurV The cum sum example is the closest what I could've found (just for reference) and what I'm asking is slightly different from that. (as I mentioned in my question) Is there any way to achieve what I want with only MySQL query?

Comment: But you haven't explained why you'd want that. And please edit your question with this information

Comment: This looks like an exhaust question identifying where the required amount is completely fulfilled.

Comment: It seems to me, that you want the fewest number of sequential rows that exceed the target value

Comment: @Strawberry Your one-sentence description is clearer than my whole question. Should I update my question again?

Comment: Of course ;-) .

Comment: Meanwhile, here's another idea to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f48b/13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN the table to itself on lesser ids (because that's what you're ordering on), summing all the rows from the join and keeping those rows whose sum is *less than* (not less than or equal) the threshold:

```
SELECT
  a.Id,
  a.Type,
  a.MyAmountCol
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b on b.id < a.id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(b.MyAmountCol), 0) < 15
```

The `COALESCE()` call is added to cater for the lowest id, which we want to keep (always), having no rows to join with.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I specified the schema and my query (which is from the answer that I linked in the question) in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f48b/1 (the first example fiddle) and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9f48b/2 (the second one). Could you elaborate more on those examples?

Comment: @lee please don't refer to code elsewhere on the web. Make your question self contained. Did you know that SQLFiddle was down for about 1 year? Other sites die or lose content. If you want an answer that refers to your SQL, then post it in your question in plain text (no images)