# MySQL Select records exceeding the cumulative total

Tags: mysql

Given I have following table

| Id | FileSizeMB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 100 |

I want to select oldest records exceeding a cumulative value, in this case say 500.

So something like this

| Id | Cumulative_FileSizeMB |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 100 |
| 5 | 200 |
| 4 | 300 |
| 3 | 400 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 1 | 600 |

I want to select only records with id 2 and 1 as they are >= 500.
Goal is to delete them.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limiting the rows to where the sum a column equals a certain value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890486/limiting-the-rows-to-where-the-sum-a-column-equals-a-certain-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with same problem.
I have reached this solution using Mysql window functions,
and also there is no need to declare a variable for cumulative total

```
SELECT * from (
  SELECT 
  id, 
  FileSizeMB,
  SUM(FileSizeMB) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS TotalFileSizeMB
  FROM table
) as t1
WHERE TotalFileSizeMB > 500
```